# OutputCache At application level mvc3

Tags: caching, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I have a MVC4/Razor website. The content is static for about a month or so - so no DB hits. Just FYI, it has Areas well.

How can I implement Caching for the entire application? Is there a way to add [OutputCache] attribute at a centralized location (say global.asax) rather than adding it to individual controllers?

Answer (score 0):

You can register the filter globally in Global.asax

```
var filters = GlobalFilters.Filters;
filters.Add(new MyOutputCacheFilter());
```

Comment: Maybe I am doing it wrong, I added the code to RegisterGlobalFilters()

// Registering the ouputcache filter for entire app. 
OutputCacheAttribute outputCache = new OutputCacheAttribute
{
   Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server,
   Duration = 86400,
   VaryByParam = "none",    
};
filters.Add(outputCache);

In firebug, i see this

Cache-Control no-cache
.
Expires -1

And under Cache Tab i see this
Expires Wed Dec 31 1969 16:00:00 

Sorry If i am missing something.

Comment: what .net version do you have?

Comment: Check this answer to see if it helps... http://stackoverflow.com/a/12052398/1242985

Comment: Hmm nope. It looks like I had to set outputCacheLocation = ServerAndClient to make it work.